# Why doesn't Count Dooku finish Anakin off?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, darth-tyranus

During their fight on Geonosis, Count Dooku cuts of Anakin's right arm leaving him pretty defenseless but rather than finish him off on the spot, he uses the force to push him across the room. Why would he do this? Was he under orders from Palpatine or is this just a simple oversight as Anakin can't die in the prequels?

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR : **There was no immediate reason to.**

---

[**Count Dooku**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku) may be operating as a Sith Lord during The Clone Wars, but in reality he is never displayed as totally evil. Unlike a true Sith Lord such as Palpatine, Darth Maul, or any of the others portrayed in Legends EU, Dooku never appears to strike out of malice. All of his attacks, each of his strategies & battle tactics, every aspect of the man seen on-screen, are practical & efficient.

During the battle with Kenobi and Skywalker, Dooku easily dispatches both Jedi with little effort. Both men are removed from the battle without killing, and Dooku does not pursue the matter for a simple reason - they are no longer a threat to him. As it is, Dooku only turned to face them since they were delaying his escape.

**Clarification:** I'm not saying he isn't evil, just that we never see him killing out of anger, rage, or enjoyment like other Sith would. Even when he needs to make an example of someone, it's not out of malice or anger - it's simply an effective tactic for discouraging others. He kills only as much as he needs to, nothing more.

Comment: He's a bit like the Borg, isn't he? And he leaves his foes demoralized and humiliated. He's the pinnacle of Sith efficiency.

Comment: How does this play into the character we see in the Clone Wars series? Regardless of people's enjoyment of the show, it is considered canon now. 

Dooku's character in the show comes across as much more cold and evil.

Comment: @David - see clarification added to answer.

Comment: Its true that he is much more calm and reserved than some of the other sith but there are moments that he seems to enjoy killing. 

The time I'm thinking of specifically is when Lok Durd is explaining the test of his new weapon on the Lurmin.

Comment: @David I could be wrong, but I took Dooku's happiness (not sure if that's the right term?) to be at the prospect of the new weapon, not at the destruction of the Lurmen.

Comment: @zaq - yes, but he also would have seen Obi-Wan, a fully trained Jedi Knight, as much more of a threat than Anakin, who was only a padawan in Dooku's eyes.

Answer (score 7):

From what we see in *Attack of the Clones* Dooku was a highly skilled and accomplished warrior. Notice how easily he dispatched both Obi-Wan and Anakin, and how he was able to hold his own against Yoda. Then, in *Revenge*, even though years have passed, he still manages to take out Obi-Wan in short order. It's not until Anakin is full of rage that he's finally overpowered. He also trained General Grievous, who summarily dispatched legions of Jedi. So basically, Dooku is one of the best Sith Lords, rivalling the most powerful Jedi.

Armed with this knowledge, let's approach the *Clones* fight. He takes out Anakin without breaking a sweat. He can totally kill the kid, but he instead leaves him maimed and humiliated. The robotic arm is a permanent reminder that Anakin is no match for him. And, as we saw in *Revenge*, he wasn't... at least, until he was overcome with rage and had the Dark Side coursing through him. When Palpatine orders Anakin to slay Dooku, you can see from the look in his eye (and I remember reading it in the *Revenge of the Sith* novel) that he finally realizes that Anakin is intended to be his replacement.

So basically, Dooku let Anakin live for the same reason he let Obi-Wan live: to humiliate them. He knew he could dispatch them at the moment of his choosing, and they knew that as well. It wasn't until he got his own hands chopped off that he realized what was really going on.

Comment: I also believe that Dooku may have been under strict instructions from his master to *not* kill Skywalker's.  After all, Sidious was planning and plotting Anakin's fall for years.  It's all speculation though.

Comment: In keeping with Sith tradition, Dooku was on the lookout for an apprentice of his own. (He had already tried and failed to recruit Obi-Wan.) Dooku might have left Anakin alive with the intention of trying to turn him to the Dark Side himself.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit I was going to mention that, but unfortunately, the majority of information we have about the Sith, including the Rule of Two and how the Sith continue their line, is no longer canon. I honestly think that's the best reason, much like how Vader tried to recruit Luke, but there's no longer any canon reason to think so. :(

Comment: The rule of two is mentioned several times in the films.